# Websphere Portal 7 getUserPrincipal().getName() returns username with ldap ip adress

Tags: jakarta-ee, ldap, websphere-7

I have 3 Websphere Portal 7 servers:
1. Production Server
2. Test Server
3. Local server
 And I have 1 Portlet Application. On Production Server and Localhost following line of code:

```
renderRequest.getUserPrincipal().getName()
```

returns username as "portaladmin". But in TEST server it returns username with LDAP ip address as 10.10.10.229:389/portaladmin. I cant find where it configured? Help, pls.

Comment: Did you check test ldap for the user?

Comment: Yes, this users exists in test ldap

Comment: You schould provide more information like WebSphere_Portal_root/config/wpconfig.properties and the user definition on ldap